# How to set cell text alignment at right in grid mvc?

Tags: model-view-controller

I have used grid mvc. I want to display cell text aligned to the right side.

This is my code:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add(c => c.PoNo).Titled("PO No").SetWidth(200);
       columns.Add(c => c.PoDate).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy}").Titled("PO Date").SetWidth(150);
       columns.Add(c => c.CompanyName).Titled("Company").SetWidth(500);
       columns.Add(c => c.PartyName).Titled("Party").SetWidth(500);
       columns.Add(c => c.Amount).Titled("PO Amount").SetWidth(400);
```

Here amount should display value at right side of the cell.

How to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a native answer to this, but I found a decent work around using css.

```
<style>
/*Simple css hack to right align text*/
td[data-name='FieldNameHere'] { 
    text-align:right;
}
</style>
```

It basically finds the td element with the right attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

```
columns.Add(c => c.Amount).Titled("PO Amount").Css("text-right);
```

This works if you have the Bootstrap.css in your site.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed this by using `RenderValueAs` and setting `Sanitized` and `Encoded` to false. I also used the `pull-right` bootstrap class:

```
columns.Add(c => c.Amount)
       .Titled("PO Amount")
       .SetWidth(400)
       .RenderValueAs(x=>String.Format("<span class=\"pull-right\">{0}</span>",c.Amount))
       .Encoded(false)
       Sanitized(false);
```